# Passing a JavaScript function to run in a new window object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, new-window

Let's say I have a HTML string that gets passed to a new window/browser using the following method:

```
var htmlStr =
        "<div><button id='copy-all'>Copy all contents</button></div>" +
        "<div id='contents-container'>" +
        "    (lots of contents are placed here...) " +
        "</div>"
   , newWin = window.open("", "Test", "width=1000, height=800, scrollbars=1, resizable=1")
   , doc = newWin.document;

doc.write(htmlStr);
```

As you can see, there will be a button (`#copy-all`) along with all the contents once the HTML string is passed to the new window and rendered.

The question is - how can I attach a JavaScript function (with or without using jQuery) to the button that enables me to manipulate the DOM placed inside the div (`#contents-container`) element? I tried including a function literal as part of the `htmlStr` variable but it doesn't seem to be a viable option.

Comment: like `doc.getElementById('copy-all').onclick = function() { alert('hi') };`?

Comment: instead of using .write use .insertAdjacentHTML;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery I would do it like this:

```
$('#copy-all', doc).on('click', function() {
    $('#contents-container', doc).html('test');
});
```

Here is a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qd8dybg0/2/ (don't forget to disable your popup blocker)

Answer (score 1):

A variant of [Mario A's answer which uses jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033927/1092820) that does not use jQuery:

```
doc.getElementById("copy-all").onclick = function(event) {
    doc.getElementById("contents-container").innerHTML = 'test';
};
```

And a demo JSFiddle (disable popup blocker to see demo): http://jsfiddle.net/kv2p8dwe/2/